# Using XPath for PMD, is there a way to account for the value of a variable in a method call?

Tags: java, eclipse, xpath, pmd

For example:

```
String user = "Daniel";
String result = doSomething(user);
```

I know I can find every occurence of `doSomething(user)` with `//MethodCall[@MethodName = "doSomething"]/ArgumentList/VariableAccess[@Name = "user"]`. Is it possible to only find those occurences, where `user` evaluates to "Daniel" at the time the method is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `MethodCall` and `VariableDeclarator` are descendants of the same `Block` element. That can be used to match the criteria

`//Block[//AssignmentExpression[last()][VariableAccess[@AccessType="WRITE" and @Name="user"]]/StringLiteral[@ConstValue="LMC"] or //VariableDeclarator[@Name="user"]/StringLiteral[@ConstValue="LMC"]]//MethodCall[@MethodName = "detectMe"]/ArgumentList/VariableAccess[@Name = "user"]`

This expresion finds `Block` elements containing a variable `user = "LMC"` either only declared or last assigned.

`//Block[//AssignmentExpression[last()][VariableAccess[@AccessType="WRITE" and @Name="user"]]/StringLiteral[@ConstValue="LMC"] or //VariableDeclarator[@Name="user"]/StringLiteral[@ConstValue="LMC"]]`

Will match something like

```
public void useIt(){
    String user = "LMC";
    String result = detectMe(user);
}
public void useIt(2){
    String user = "Daniel";
    
    user = "osoo";
    user = "LMC";
    String result = detectMe(user);
}
```

As a general method, a test class with the relevant use case can be written and dumped with `pmd` for later XML analysis

`pmd ast-dump --format xml --language java --file PMDSource.java > PMDSource.java.xml`

then use any XPath aware tool to test the expression

```
 xmllint --xpath '//Block[//AssignmentExpression[last()][VariableAccess[@AccessType="WRITE" and @Name="user"]]/StringLiteral[@ConstValue="LMC"] or //VariableDeclarator[@Name="user"]/StringLiteral[@ConstValue="LMC"]]//MethodCall[@MethodName = "detectMe"]/ArgumentList/VariableAccess[@Name = "user"]' PMDSource.java.xml
```

Result

```
<VariableAccess AccessType="READ" CompileTimeConstant="false" Expression="true" Image="user" Name="user" ParenthesisDepth="0" Parenthesized="false"/>
<VariableAccess AccessType="READ" CompileTimeConstant="false" Expression="true" Image="user" Name="user" ParenthesisDepth="0" Parenthesized="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tho I realise my question was a bit unprecise.
Staying with your example, I want to know if you can find elements containing a variable with the value "LMC" without knowing the name of the variable. Also your XPath is correct in this example, but it would also find elements, where user was "G Knucklez" at the time of the method call which then only later becomes declared as 'user = "LMC"'.

Comment: This will find a variable with "LMC" as value regardless of its name `//VariableDeclarator[@Name]/StringLiteral[@ConstValue="LMC"]`. As for your second question, please add that use case to the question. Also, please consider accepting the answer as it answers your original question.

Comment: I don't think that it answers the original question as it does not only find the occurences where user evaluates to "LMC" during method call. The variable can evaluate to anything and it would still be found by your code, as long as user was declared "LMC" at some point in the same Block.
For example `user = "LMC" ; user = "Daniel" ; detectMe(user) ;` would be found, even tho user does not evaluate to "LMC" any more.

Comment: @GKnucklez answer was updated